# Create different service with the same class (android)

Tags: android, android-intent, timer, android-service

I have to create an app for sending programmed messages, if I create a single service for a single message is all ok, but if I create messages how do I handle the deletion of a specific service? also after the stop of the first service if i try to create other service crash all... i use a timer for my service

```
public class service extends Service
{
    private static Timer timer = new Timer(); 
    int i=1;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        super.onCreate();


    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags,int startId){



        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new mainTask(), 0, 20*1000);
        return service.START_NOT_STICKY;


    }

    @Override 
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "distrutta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("PROVA SERVICE", "Distruzione Service");


    }
    private class mainTask extends TimerTask
    { 
        public void run() 
        {
            toastHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }


    }  private final Handler toastHandler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {

            if (i==1)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                i++;}
            else
            {
                i=0;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fine", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                stopSelf();

                timer.cancel();


            }
        }
    };
```

service call:

```
        Intent i=(new Intent(this,service.class));
        startService(i);
```

Comment: stop with specific id of the message

Comment: But for call different service i have to use different intent no? 

    Intent i=(new Intent(this,service.class)); 
    i.setData(Uri.parse(time)); 
    startService(i);

time for example is the systemclock,with this code i create two service with different intent?